# How can I define a custom Contact Form in an Installation profile / distribution?

Tags: 8, installation-profiles

**Question** : How can I define a custom Contact Form in an Installation profile / distribution ?

**Goal** :

[image]

**Research :** :
It's for an installation profile we want to put an contact form in all our Drupal installations in the install profile. It's a little bigger than the default Drupal 8 forms. I have also content-types created for that profile with YAML-files. We can build forms in a module with the Form API but how can we that achieve that in an install profile ? In Drupal 8, i think all the configuration is in YAML.

**Expected solution :** I want to rebuild the form and put it into an installation profile with the captcha included. I used there the Drupal module Re-captcha for. Is this also with the YAML-files or in _install function ?

Is that possible ? Are they better/other methods for achieving this goal ?

Comment: I am also looking for the solution of this. Can someone please help?